# Randomly Selected Data from Database with Constraints

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have created a MySQL Database with a vast number of products and their cost. I utilize EF6 to wrap the database.

Based on the given input, I need to generate at random, a correct selection that meets the described criteria.

For example:
10 Items, Total Value $25

I am at a loss as how to properly go about iterating through the database to produce the required results.

What I am currently doing seems terribly inefficent:

```
using (var db = new Database())
            {
                var packageSelected = false;
                var random = new Random();
                var minItemId = (from d in db.products select d.id).Min();
                var maxItemId = (from d in db.products select d.id).Max();

                var timer = new Stopwatch();

                timer.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Trying to make package...");

                while (!packageSelected)
                {
                    var currentItems = new List<int>();
                    for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
                    {
                        var randomItem = random.Next(minItemId, maxItemId);
                        currentItems.Add(randomItem);
                    }

                    decimal? packageValue = 0;
                    currentItems.ForEach(o =>
                    {
                        var firstOrDefault = db.products.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == o);
                        if (firstOrDefault != null)
                        {
                            var value = firstOrDefault.MSRP;
                            packageValue += value;
                        }
                    });
                    if (!(packageValue >= 25) || !(packageValue <= 26)) continue;
                    packageSelected = true;
                    timer.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Took {0} seconds.", timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                    currentItems.ForEach(o =>
                    {
                        var firstOrDefault = db.products.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == o);
                        if (firstOrDefault != null)
                            Console.WriteLine("Item: {0} - Price: ${1}", firstOrDefault.DESCRIPTION, 
                                firstOrDefault.MSRP);
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: If any of your items exceeds 1.01 in cost you have an infinite loop. i.e. 24.99 + 1.02 == 26.01

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
public virtual TEntity GetRandom()
{
      return DBSet.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1).First();
}
public List<TEntity> Random(int amount, int maxprice)
    {
        var list = new List<TEntity>();
        var tempPrice = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < amount; i++)
        {
            var element = GetRandom();
            tempPrice += element.Price;
            if (tempPrice > maxprice)
            {
                return list;
            }
            list.Add(element);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

hope this helps

**EDIT:** If the maxprice is reached before the required amount of elements, the for-loop will stop and you won't get the full amount of elements.